# Leaflet angular. can i write a loop inside an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, leaflet

I have the following code

```
$scope.paths = {
    p1: {
        color: '#008000',
        weight: 8,
        latlngs: [
            { lat: Number(route.data[0].stops[0].latitude), lng: Number(route.data[0].stops[0].longitude) },
            { lat: Number(route.data[0].stops[1].latitude), lng: Number(route.data[0].stops[1].longitude) },
            { lat: Number(route.data[0].stops[2].latitude), lng: Number(route.data[0].stops[2].longitude) }
        ],
}};
```

For this I grab data from a .json file using angular's $http service and store it as 'route'. Then i use 'route' to grab data from the json and pass it to the latlngs array.

```
latlngs: [
    { lat: Number(route.data[0].stops[0].latitude), lng: Number(route.data[0].stops[0].longitude) },
    { lat: Number(route.data[0].stops[1].latitude), lng: Number(route.data[0].stops[1].longitude) },
    { lat: Number(route.data[0].stops[2].latitude), lng: Number(route.data[0].stops[2].longitude) }
],
```

This works as expected.
But i have to write a new line for each item in my json array. Can i do a loop inside this array to grab the data? Something like:

```
latlngs: [ 
    for (var i = 0, i <route.data[0].stops, i++){
        {
            lat: Number(route.data[0].stops[i].latitude),
            lng: Number(route.data[0].stops[i].longitude) 
        }
    }
]
```